# How to make a clickable link with HTML Editey

Tags: html, links, text-editor

I am an HTML beginner and I'm making a website using HTML Editey. I know how to do things like make bold text or make an underline under the letter or number, but I don't know how to make a clickable link.

I want to make a clickable link or some text which is you click on it, it will make you go to another website. I did inspect on Chrome but I got confused and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: HTML Editey is a Chrome plugin that allows you to edit HTML documents as part of Google Docs: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-editey/jgmngefpkkgnhkgffnldnpinipphceob

Comment: Questions about web site programming are off topic here and should, instead, be asked on Stackoverflow.

Comment: This is a question about a specific piece of software used by webmasters.   I'm pretty sure that it would be off-topic at StackOverflow.     While the answers so far have focused on code, another good answer could focus on screenshots of the UI that show which buttons to press.

Answer (score 1):

Make a .html File with the following content:

```
 <a href="http://website.com"> The Text </a>
```

It's simple, isn't it?

More information: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: Have you confirmed that that works with HTML Editey?

Comment: It's a screenshot with a HTML Link made like this in the chrome web store so i think it should work ;-) (And a html editor which does not support offical html tags would be very bad)

Answer (score 0):

Its really quite simple, and we were all new programmers at some point and time.

You can use this link for anything really not just text.

```
<a href="">Your Content here</a>
```

That is the basic code for linking objects. It will be the same with images or divs all the same you would just add the content in the same area.

Div Example: `<a href=""><div>div is a link</div></a>`

Img Example: `<a href=""><img src=""></a>`